# How can I make a face verification system?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, cnn, embeddings

I'm building a face verification system using face embeddings (of 512 dimensions) from a pretrained *Facenet* model. For this, if I have some 4 to 5 images for a person, how can I successfully verify a new unseen images as either the same or different person?

I think this of **one class classification** (because of having single class) task, and googled it, but unable to find any reliable sources which suits well for this task.

Then, I've trained a SVM classifier with embeddings of a person and also with dummy embeddings of some 4 to 5 persons (so that having positive and negative classes). But it doesn't seem to work well.

Please suggest me with a ML algorithm/technique for this task, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming Facenet is an image classifier and it will give embedding for a face similar to other CNNs. If that is the case you don't need to train different classifiers, you can just remove the head of Facenet and initialize a small network on top of it and train an end to end network for better accuracies.